# Unexpected runtime ID error when trying to use the Run and Debug feature in Visual Studio on Windows 10 x86 with c# csproj

Tags: c#, csproj

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH19J.jpg)

What is the solution for unexpected runtimeid win10 x86

The image has been attached above

Using running and debugging results unexpected runtimeid win10 x86 and which is telling me open launch json and I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error and spent a week trying to figure it out and I finally hit a solution. the environment variable for dotnet is ordered incorrectly within your machine. to fix this:

- type in "environment" on your windows start button
- click "edit the system environment variables"
- click "Environment Variables" towards the bottom
- under system variables scroll down to "Path" and hit "Edit"
- find "C:\Program Files\dotnet"
  -if "C:\Program Files\dotnet" is **BELOW** "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet" move it **up** above "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet"
- next if you have vs code or visual studio open, close them all down, open up all of them, and delete any bin or obj files within your project.
  hit the debugger and it should now be debugging correctly without the runtimeId error.